# Record Display won't update after ComboBox selection

Tags: sharepoint, combobox, ms-access-2010

We're using an Access Application that presents a ComboBox built off of a query that polls a Sharepoint list, then shows the details for that record when clicked.

It's worked perfectly for seven months or so, but today, one of the users ran into an issue when trying to add a new record to the List.  After the ComboBox would update with the new entry, clicking on it would not update the display of that record.  The highlight in the ComboBox would move, but the details would still reflect the last record chosen.

Thankfully (?) I can re-create the issue on my copy of the client application, so I can troubleshoot it and also prove that it's a repeatable issue, not just a sporadic bug.

Here's what I've got so far:

- Restarting the affected form allowed normal operation to continue, but while that's an acceptable workaround, it's obviously not an acceptable solution.
- Editing existing records does not trigger the issue.  The edited records display perfectly.
- None of the fields in the problem List are 'required'.
- The Sharepoint List in question has about 1700 records, so it's not a large database at all, and on top of that, the ComboBox is only displaying a Query that returns 30-50 records.
- Made a test form that recreated a similar environment for one of the other Sharepoint lists in the DB and got the same response...  or... lack of response.... from the ComboBox after adding a new record.
- VB Calculations do not appear to be affected and can use the new records in formulae, despite heavy usage of Recordsets to compile those values.

Any advice will be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This looks simply like the form is not refreshing the values, try pressing F9 (ReCalc) or F5 (ReQuery) and see if the value updates.  There is a bug on access forms where going back from a new record and then forward again seems to stop recalculation - this seemed to fix it for me:-

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.Recalc
End Sub
```

Comment: Requery was already in practice in this situation, but Recalc was not. I had the opportunity to test ReCalc with this issue today, but unfortunately, there was no difference. The selection did not properly update to show the newly added record.

Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Comment: @TesseractE Have you tried moving the focus away from the combobox before the requery, and then setting it back afterwards, odd I know but sometimes Access is funny unless the focus is moved?